# How to compile a project with C++11 under Xcode 8?

Tags: c++, xcode

This question was asked many times and I failed to replicate all of the solutions I could find. I am unable to find this setting under File->Project Settings (as some suggested). Please be very specific. If you know an answer for Xcode 7, chances are it will work for me too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the same for 7 and 8. From the Project Navigator, select the project.  In the main panel, at the top left, select the target.  Now the main panel should have General, Resource Tags, Build Settings, Build Phases, & Build Rules along the top.  Select Build Settings, select All.  Scroll down to "Apple LLVM 8.0 Language C++" and expand it.  Change "C++ Language Dialect" to "C++11 [-std=c++11]".

Comment: Under Build Settings, make sure All is selected (Basic, Customized, All)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm getting compile error: cstdio file not found

Comment: @shantanu What is the extension of the file you are compiling?

Comment: For Xcode 8, the value to set it to is `c++11`, it adds the `-std=` bit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Build Settings -> Linking-> other linker flags -> add to "-lc++"