# Xcode C++11 compilation issues

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

Im new to C++ and am working my way through www.learncpp.com. Xcode is raising an error with a struct declaration:

```
struct Monster{

int health;
std::string name;
MonsterType type;
};
```

The error raised is:  ***Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers*** and is pointed at the first line `struct...`. This code compiles fine with Visual Studio 2015. I have setup my build settings according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522270/4318096%20%22this') so it should be C++11 compatible. What could be going wrong? Some have suggested it is clang.

Comment: what is the `!!`? Pretty sure it's not valid C++

Comment: You have a freaky character after the `{`.

Comment: From what you posted, you should be getting an error message about `MonsterType` not being defined.

Comment: If it's not the freaky character, do you have this code in a `.mm`-file? A `.m`-file would not permit to mix objective-c with c++.

Comment: Thanks! I retyped that out and it compiled. I couldn't see that character in Xcode :| So strange